# How can I understand the ORDER BY clause in the below mentioned SQL query?

Tags: sql

I was doing an assignment where I did not get this SQL query right. The question was:

> Excluding $0.00, what is the minimum bi-weekly high rate of pay (please include the dollar sign and decimal point in your answer)?

What I did:

```
Select 
MIN(Biweekly_high_Rate)
FROM salary_range_by_job_classification
WHERE MIN(Biweekly_high_rate)>0;
```

But this gave me answer as 0. And 0 isn't the correct answer
 Then I looked at the solution. And I didn't understand the last line of solution

```
Select Biweekly_high_Rate
From salary_range_by_job_classification
ORDER BY LENGTH(Biweekly_high_Rate) ASC, Biweekly_high_Rate ASC;
```

How can I understand the ORDER BY statement?

Comment: These two queries appear to be doing different intended things.  Can you make your question more concrete by adding sample data and the expected output?

Comment: You should most likely also tag a specifc database as `LENGTH()` is not a ANSI/ISO SQL standard function which the `sql` tag on this website is about.. Unless the more modern SQL standards 2006+ (which i dont own) have added `LENGTH()`

Comment: *" Excluding $0.00, what is the minimum bi-weekly high rate of pay"*  Wierd there is a `LENGTH()` used there.. I also don't fully get why? `LENGTH()` gives a string length and ideally should be used on string datatypes .. like @TimBiegeleisen said it is unclear why the last query is correct .. **But i find it highly wierd and highly  suspicious to find a minimum bi-weekly high rate of pay which suggests a decimal like of datatype with a `LENGTH()` function**

Comment: `WHERE MIN(Biweekly_high_rate)>0` is invalid standard SQL to begin with. It would result in an error in most database products

Comment: What is the data type of `Biweekly_high_Rate`?

Answer (score 1):

The following should work as well:

```
SELECT
MIN(Biweekly_high_Rate)
FROM salary_range_by_job_classification
WHERE Biweekly_High_Rate <> '$0.00'
ORDER BY Biweekly_High_Rate ASC;
```

You are selecting the min Biweekly_high_Rate `FROM` the table
Using `WHERE <> '$0.00'` you are excluding values that are equal to zero.

Then you are `ORDERING by` the Biweekly_High_Rate to get the first value correct.

Comment: This query returns only one row - no need for `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 0):

I'd infer that `biweekly_high_rate` is a number, but the column is defined as a string. This is not good database design, because strings don't sort the same as numbers. Consider the following numbers and their proper order:

```
Numeric ordering:        Alphabetical ordering:
2                        11
11                       110
12                       12
110                      2
```

One way to handle this is to sort all the strings of length 1 first, then all the strings of length 2, then all the strings of length 3, and so on. Then to break the tie within each group, sort alphabetically. The solution to sort by the length first, then by the value, achieves this.

But it would be smarter to define the column as a number instead of a string, if that's the way the author intended to use the data. It would have other advantages too, for example allowing an index on the column to optimize the sorting. It would also take less storage space to store numbers as numbers instead of strings.

It's puzzling that the second query claims to be a solution, because it doesn't exclude the 0.00 values, and it doesn't find the minimum value. I would talk to the instructor about this during office hours, and ask why it's considered the solution.

Is the column storing strings like `'$0.00'` with the dollar sign and all? That's not conventional database design either, because currency formatting should not be stored in the database.

Your first query is actually much closer to the answer I would give. Except you can't use `MIN()` in a WHERE clause. Aggregate functions like `MIN()` need to work on groups of rows, but the WHERE clause only works row-by-row.

This may work:

```
Select 
MIN(Biweekly_high_Rate)
FROM salary_range_by_job_classification
WHERE Biweekly_high_rate>0;
```

But this is still making an assumption that the `biweekly_high_rate` is supposed to be a numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Biweekly_high_Rate
From salary_range_by_job_classification
ORDER BY LENGTH(Biweekly_high_Rate) ASC, Biweekly_high_Rate ASC;
```

To clarify what you ask, and to expand on what Bill mentioned about the column should be NUMERIC basis, not string, the ORDER BY is basically applying a double-sort.

First think of getting a list of people and you want them ordered alphabetically by last name, then first name.  We think of this rather simple all last names alphabetically first, then all first names.  But what happens if you have 5 names last name smith. The secondary sort is by first name.

```
Jones Gary
…
Smith, Adam
Smith, Betty
Smith, Joe
Smith, Nancy
Smith, Veronica
…
Walker, Tim
```

So the order by if there are multiple fields listed does the primary sort on the first field.  Then once all those are sorted, WITHIN each at that level, the secondary sort is next and so on where you might have an order by with 3, 4 or even more columns.

Now, back to your example.  As Bill mentioned, it APPEARS your data for the biweekly high rate is a string value.  So, the ordering by LENGTH(Biweekly_Hi_Rate) ASC means to FIRST sort by the length of the string representation in Ascending order (hence ASC vs DESCending).  After that first level sort, THEN sort by the biweekly hi rate itself.

So, lets take the following example of STRING-BASED Rates and the implied LENGTH() of those strings.

```
BiWeeklyHiRate
13
5
11
9
14
2
10
```

Same order, but just showing the length.

```
LENGTH of string    BiWeeklyHiRate
2                   13
1                   5
2                   11
1                   9
2                   14
1                   2
2                   10
```

Now, if just ordering by the LENGTH() of the biweekly.  Notice the weekly rates have all the single-length rates first, THEN all the 2-digit rates second.  But notice within each length in common, the weekly rate is NOT sorted.

```
LENGTH of string    BiWeeklyHiRate
1                   5
1                   9
1                   2
2                   13
2                   11
2                   14
2                   10
```

So now, the SECONDARY sort of the rate is applied giving

```
LENGTH of string    BiWeeklyHiRate
1                   2
1                   5
1                   9
2                   10
2                   11
2                   13
2                   14
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work, as we are providing condition WHERE NOT Biweekly_high_Rate = "$0.00"

```
Select 
min(Biweekly_high_Rate)
From salary_range_by_job_classification
WHERE NOT Biweekly_high_Rate = "$0.00"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select  min(Biweekly_high_Rate) 
From salary_range_by_job_classification 
WHERE Biweekly_High_Rate <> '$0.00' and LENGTH(Biweekly_high_Rate)<7
```

I think this is an easy way to get $15.00 but the real answer in coursera is $100.00 and i have no idea about it

Comment: A little explanation is preferable instead of a code only answer.

Comment: Oh sorry sir, I was new at stackoverflow. I edited the comment but it didn't give the right answer on coursera

Answer (score 0):

It is clearer to use `like`:

```
SELECT Biweekly_high_Rate FROM salary_range_by_job_classification
WHERE Biweekly_high_rate NOT LIKE ("$0.00")
ORDER BY LENGTH(Biweekly_high_rate) ASC, Biweekly_high_rate ASC;
```

The last line orders the rows in ascending order.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT
min(Biweekly_high_Rate)
FROM salary_range_by_job_classification
WHERE NOT Biweekly_high_Rate LIKE '$0.00'
```

the column storing strings like '$0.00' with the dollar sign and all? That's not conventional database design either, because currency formatting should not be stored in the database.

All i'm saying is i have gone through the same assignment from SQL for DS from UCDAVIS in coursera and the " = " operator will not work there because of above error so use LIKE operator.